# What is an efficient way operating a set of variables?

Tags: java

I am making a "genetic simulator", and at some point I want to compare the data in the genes to set the result in an individual. I came to a solution, but seems quite impractical, I'm sure there is a proper way of doing it

Right now, I use a static method in a support class that handles the operation, but I fear that maintenance will be annoying, as I plan to modify the list of attributes quite often.

```
public class GeneOps {  
    public static AttributeList AddAttributeLists (AttributeList a, AttributeList b) {
        AttributeList x=new AttributeList();

        x.agressiveness= a.agressiveness+b.agressiveness;
        x.bravery=a.bravery+b.bravery;
        x.speed=a.speed+b.speed;
        //Repeat for all attributes

        return x;
    }
}
```

this works, but I would like something that is updated automatically every time I decide to add something to the list EG: If I add an attribute called sneak, I want it to be calculated without modifying the method.

Comment: Give the AttributeList a public instance `addAttributes(AttributeList al)` method where the attributes from `al` are added to the current list, the `this`

Comment: you mean adding all variables of AttributeList into a [] or a <>?  how di I do that?

Comment: No, none of the above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be if all attributes are represented by a numeric value then you could make the actual attributes an enum, something like:

```
public enum Attribute {
    AGGRESSIVENESS, BRAVERY, SPEED, WISDOM, INTELLIGENCE, CHARISMA, DEXTERITY // more as needed
}
```

And then in the class that holds the attributes, use a `Map<Attribute, Integer>` which can be assigned an `EnumMap<Attribute, Integer>` if need be, and which can easily add two maps of attributes together by iterating through the Map using the enum as key:

```
// add all values of this object's attributes with 2nd map
public void addAttributes(Map<Attribute, Integer> attributes2) {
    for (Attribute attribute : Attribute.values()) {
        int value = attributes.get(attribute) + attributes2.get(attribute);
        attributes.put(attribute, value);
    }
}
```

And safer still would be to check for empty (null) map values and correct for them:

```
// add all values of this object's attributes with 2nd map
public void addAttributes(Map<Attribute, Integer> attributes2) {
    for (Attribute attribute : Attribute.values()) {
        int value = attributes.get(attribute) != null ? attributes.get(attribute) : 0;
        int value +=  attributes2.get(attribute) != null ? attributes2.get(attribute) : 0;
        attributes.put(attribute, value);
    }
}
```

For example:

```
public class Individual {
    private Map<Attribute, Integer> attributes;

    // default constructor
    public Individual() {
        // create map and initialize all attributes to 0
        attributes = new EnumMap<>(Attribute.class);
        for (Attribute attribute : Attribute.values()) {
            attributes.put(attribute, 0);
        }
    }

    // constructor that sets attributes
    public Individual(Map<Attribute, Integer> attributes) {
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }

    public Map<Attribute, Integer> getAttributes() {
        return attributes;
    }

    public void setAttributes(Map<Attribute, Integer> attributes) {
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }

    public void setAttribute(Attribute attribute, int value) {
        attributes.put(attribute, value);
    }

    public int getAttribute(Attribute attribute) {
        return attributes.get(attribute).intValue();
    }

    // add all values of this object's attributes with 2nd map
    public void addAttributes(Map<Attribute, Integer> attributes2) {
        for (Attribute attribute : Attribute.values()) {
            int value = attributes.get(attribute) != null ? attributes.get(attribute) : 0;
            int value +=  attributes2.get(attribute) != null ? attributes2.get(attribute) : 0;
            attributes.put(attribute, value);
        }
    }

    public void addAttributes(Individual individual2) {
        addAttributes(individual2.getAttributes());
    }

     public String displayAttributes() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        // ... iterate through the attributes appending to the StringBuilder
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks very interesting and has concepts that I barely scratched the surface, such as enums and maps, I will take a detailed look at it, try to implement it and get back to you. Thanks! //5 min later and having a quick look at the concept of maps, this might be exactly what I need!

Comment: This will do it, I will have to re-structure some things, but this will do the trick, and I learnt a valuable bit in the process. Thanks!